# scaleQuantile function doesn't output what I expect

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm using `d3.scaleQuantile()` to get some specific output of numbers, the range of the `d3.scaleQuantile()` is an array of 8 numbers. I console.log() a number in the middle position of the range, it returns the first one of that range. The code looks like this

```
var sortMass = d3.scaleQuantile()
    .domain([minMass, maxMass])
    .range([2000,4000,6000,8000,100000,120000])
console.log(sortMass(6500)) // here shows 2000
```

If it returns either 6000 or 8000, that makes more sense. But I can't figure out why the output is 2000. I read over the D3 documentation, but I'm still confused. Anyone can explain how the `d3.scaleQuantile()` function works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a misunderstanding here: in a D3 scale, any kind of scale, you don't pass a value within the range to the scale. Instead of that, you pass a value within the **domain**.

So, given your scale...

```
var sortMass = d3.scaleQuantile()
  .domain([minMass, maxMass])
  .range([2000, 4000, 6000, 8000, 100000, 120000]);
```

... if you pass the scale a value **between minMass and maxMass**, it will return the correspondent value in the range.

Here is a basic demo, where I'm setting `minMass` to `0` and `maxMass` to `100`:

```js
var minMass = 0,
  maxMass = 100;
var sortMass = d3.scaleQuantile()
  .domain([minMass, maxMass])
  .range([2000, 4000, 6000, 8000, 100000, 120000]);

d3.range(0, 110, 10).forEach(function(d) {
  console.log("for the value " + d + ", the output is:" + sortMass(d))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

I suspect that you're using the limits of the range as `minMass` and `maxMass`. If that is the case indeed, it won't work: the domain is divided in **equal** segments. Let's prove it:

```js
var sortMass = d3.scaleQuantile()
  .domain([2000,120000])
  .range([2000, 4000, 6000, 8000, 100000, 120000]);

console.log(sortMass(6500))
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

And that `2000` in the output is proper expected.

Therefore, if my assumption above is correct, you should use a threshold scale instead:

```js
var thresholds = [2000, 4000, 6000, 8000, 100000, 120000];
var sortMass = d3.scaleThreshold()
  .domain(thresholds)
  .range(thresholds);

console.log(sortMass(6500))
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

**Conclusion:**

So, to answer your question:

> Can anyone explain how the `d3.scaleQuantile()` function works?

For any D3 scale, you pass a value according to the **domain**, and the scale will return a value according to the **range**. Remember:

- **Domain** → is the input.
- **Range** → is the output.

Comment: Thank you so much Gerardo!! The answer is so explicit and so helpful. But according to your answer, I'm still confused about what you said that >the domain is divided in equal segments. I did use the limits of range as minMass and maxMass. Could you explain that a bit further, how the domain is divided equally and why it won't work? Thanks again!

Comment: if you use 2000 to 120000, you have a gap of 118000. That divided by 6 is approximately 20000. So, only after 20000 the output range will be the next one.